# Scrapy returns 0 items and 0 crawled pages

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

please I need help. I am learning scraping and have been struggling to get it work scraping a website.

I get 0 items crawled every time. I have used user_agent and also set robot_txt = False in the settings.py and yet it doesn't work.

I notice when I use scrapy shell, I get all the details and have checked through my codes again and again to find errors but can't still find it. Please someone should help me check and tell me where I got it wrong.
spider code:

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
    from  batt_data.items import BattDataItem
    import urllib.parse
    
    class BatterySpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'battery' 
        allowed_domains = ['web']
        start_urls = ['https://www.made-in-china.com/multi- 
        search/24v%2Bbattery/F1/1.html']
        base_url = ['https://www.made-in-china.com/multi- 
        search/24v%2Bbattery/F1/1.html']
    
        rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class, 
            "nextpage")]'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        )
    
        def parse_item(self, response):
            item = BattDataItem()
            item['description'] = response.xpath('//img[@class="J-firstLazyload"]/@alt').extract()
            item['chemistry'] = response.xpath('//li[@class="J-faketitle ellipsis"][1]/span/text()').extract()
            item['applications'] = response.xpath('//li[@class="J-faketitle ellipsis"][2]/span/text()').extract()
            item['shape'] = response.xpath('//li[@class="J-faketitle ellipsis"][4]/span/text()').extract()
            item['discharge_rate'] = response.xpath('//li[@class="J-faketitle ellipsis"][5]/span/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

log file:

```
C:\Users\Ikeen\batt_data>scrapy crawl battery
    2020-08-29 21:17:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: batt_data)
    2020-08-29 21:17:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.1.0.0, libxml2 2.9.4, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 17.2.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017), cryptography 2.0.3, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
    2020-08-29 21:17:27 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
    2020-08-29 21:17:27 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
    {'BOT_NAME': 'batt_data',
     'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'batt_data.spiders',
     'SPIDER_MODULES': ['batt_data.spiders'],
     'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    2020-08-29 21:17:27 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 549b17173b135b6b
    2020-08-29 21:17:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
    ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
     'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
     'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
    2020-08-29 21:17:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
    ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
    2020-08-29 21:17:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
    ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
    2020-08-29 21:17:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
    []
    2020-08-29 21:17:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
    2020-08-29 21:17:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2020-08-29 21:17:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
    2020-08-29 21:17:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.made-in-china.com/multi-search/24v%2Bbattery/F1/1.html> (referer: None)
    2020-08-29 21:17:30 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.made-in-china.com': <GET https://www.made-in-china.com/multi-search/24v%2Bbattery/F1/2.html;jsessionid=2B77F23449911847145999CD6E9B6429>
    2020-08-29 21:17:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
    2020-08-29 21:17:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 234,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 54381,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.42789,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 20, 17, 30, 804912),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
     'log_count/INFO': 10,
     'offsite/domains': 1,
     'offsite/filtered': 1,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 20, 17, 28, 377022)}
    2020-08-29 21:17:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2020-08-29 21:17:30 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.made-in-china.com': <GET https://www.made-in-china.com/multi-search/24v%2Bbattery/F1/2.html;jsessionid=2B77F23449911847145999CD6E9B6429>
```

Your request is being filtered as it doesn't belong to the allowed domains that you defined.

```
    allowed_domains = ['web']
```

Use `allowed_domains = ['made-in-china.com']` or remove it completely.